# Passing values between components in React

Tags: reactjs, components

I m beginner to reactJS and I m having so much trouble with self learning.

I want to print the data I get from first page.
I used 2 .js files

This is userpage.js:

```
import resultPage from "./resultPage";
// JS
//const input = document.getElementById('myText');
//const inputValue = input.value
// React
// value, onChange

const Multi = () => {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({ firstName: "", email: "", age: "" });
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setPerson({ ...person, [name]: value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    //e.preventDefault();

    if (person.firstName && person.email && person.age) {
      const newPerson = { ...person, id: new Date().getTime().toString() };
      setPeople([...people, newPerson]);
      setPerson({ firstName: "", email: "", age: "" });
      resultPage(people, person);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <article className="form">
        <form>
          <div className="form-control">
            <label htmlFor="firstName">Name : </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              value={person.firstName}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-control">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email : </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              value={person.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-control">
            <label htmlFor="age">Age : </label>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="age"
              name="age"
              value={person.age}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            add person
          </button>
        </form>
      </article>
    </>
  );
};

export default Multi;
```

This has 2 textboxes and a submit button.

This code is from resultPage.js:

```
function resultPage(people, person) {
  return (
    <article>
      {people.map((person) => {
        const { id, firstName, email, age } = person;
        return (
          <div key={id} className="item">
            <h4>{firstName}</h4>
            <p>{email}</p>
            <p>{age}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </article>
  );
}
export default resultPage;
```

What am I doing wrong? I m new to reactjs. So kindly spare my obvious mistakes and help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `resultPage` in `handleSubmit`. That's not going to work. You want `resultPage` to be part of the rendering, probably conditionally.

Consider something like:

```
return <>
    {person.firstName !== "" && <resultPage people={people} person={person} />}
    {person.firstName === "" && <>
        // the form
    </>}
</>;
```

Also since `resultPage` is a component, it's best to capitalize it.

---

I think you probably want a 3rd component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [ people, setPeople ] = React.useState([]);
    const [ isEditing, setIsEditing ] = React.useState(false);

    return <>
        {isEditing && <Multi setPeople={(people) => {
            setPeople(people);
            setIsEditing(false);
        }}
        {isEditing === false && <resultPage people={people} />}
    </>;
}
```

`Mutli` now accepts a prop `setPeople` that is called in `handleSubmit`.

Comment: which page should I add this ?

Comment: Add it to `Multi`.

Comment: Still doesnt work like i want it to. Doesnt pass data to next page. and print on it.

Comment: I think I know what you're looking for, see my updated answer.

Comment: third component like another .js file? and this one actually sends data to result page?

Comment: Yes. I see `Multi` as being a component that 'edits' a list of people. `resultPage` is a component that displays a list of people. The 3rd component ties those two together.

Answer (score 0):

From [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

> HTML form elements work a bit differently from other DOM elements in React, because form elements naturally keep some internal state.

You need to add `handleSubmit` to your form, and it'll work. As @Halcyon suggested, using a Capital case for a component is good. It's tough to distinguish between HTML elements and components if you use lowercase. [Read this](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) for more details.

I am attaching a working sandbox for your code.

[image: Edit modest-marco-nnk6dy]